# Parallel Programming in lab view is it possible?

Tags: labview

I want to know two things regarding parallel programming,
First, now a days how much processor supports parallel processing, if someone give me a link of any survey paper or website link in which they defined clearly.
Second, is it possible, i will do parallel programming in lab-view, if yes then how much it is efficient in lab-view, if i do some task, please send me a link for further details or send me sample code. thanks

Comment: Did you try to google it out? Of course LabVIEW supports parallelism, and quite efficiently - http://www.ni.com/tutorial/9393/en/, http://www.ni.com/white-paper/6422/en/, etc.

Comment: yes i checked, but i want some accurate results,that how much it is efficient in lab-view

Comment: But what do you exactly mean, please? Which criteria/parameters do you expect to see? Like, how you'd like to measure efficiency of parallel programming in LabVIEW?
Also, what is important - what kind of the application would you like to implement? Maybe, for your app you don't need to go so deep into this topic, but just implement it, and it would work efficiently?

Comment: i want to increase the efficiency of algorithm in term of speed, so i just want to implement parallel technique to increase its speed. if you feel comfortable then please share your email address i will talk to you on call. Thanks

Comment: Then, just follow advices from NI, regarding how to speed up algorithms (for example, for array processing, etc.); use Iterational Parallelism of for loops, implement some code on FPGA/or even by using CUDA.

Comment: I tried to improve your post and you reverted back to your original.  The mind boogles.  FWIW, now a days is spelt nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to do? If what you want is to have several parallel tasks, it is easy, each loop will execute independently, so place as many loops as you want in the block diagram.

If you plan to go further, launch asynchronously several VIs ( with the tasks you want to parallelize)  with "Asynchronous calls" https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvconcepts/asynchronous_vi_calls/
In this way you will have several VIs running in parallel in the background.

For hardware optimization what is proposed in http://www.ni.com/tutorial/9393/en/, as already mentioned ,  will speed up the execution.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i will check it accordingly you. If i feel some difficulties i will let you know. Thanks